# How do I configure multiple layout templates in a layout and use it when using the express-handlebars template engine?

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

How do I configure multiple layout templates in a layout and use it when using the express-handlebars template engine?

By default, there is only one main.handlebars front-end template in the layout. If I still have a background page template, it is placed in the layout file for the admin background page. How should I configure it?

Is this a configuration that belongs to express?
Seeking advice!
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHbN9.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./config/key').mongoURI;
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    //Here you can directly add another template file adminIndex? Is this OK?Because the background layout is inconsistent with the foreground.
    layout:'adminIndex'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

There is no similar problem solving method in the network, so I am confused.